# Join unique strings from an array of objects

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have an array of objects containing strings.

```
var values = new object[5];
values[0] = "PIZZA HUT";
values[1] = "ISLAMABAD";
values[2] = "ISLAMABAD";
values[3] = "PAKISTAN";
values[4] = "PAKISTAN";
```

I want to get a string of unique elements from the array, joined with `,` also need to check if string isNullOrWhiteSpace;

```
PIZZA HUT, ISLAMABAD, PAKISTAN.
```

Currently I am doing the following. But you can see that it required to much checks in the if statement. I was wondering if there is **a better way using LINQ**

```
string featureName = values[0] as string;
string adminboundry4 = values[1] as string;
string adminboundry3 = values[2] as string;
string adminboundry2 = values[3] as string;
string adminboundry1 = values[4] as string;


if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adminboundry4) 
   && adminboundry4 != adminboundry1 
   && adminboundry4 != adminboundry2 
   && adminboundry4 != adminboundry3) //want to get rid of these checks
                featureName += "," + adminboundry4;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adminboundry3)) //Not checking for duplicate here just for this question
                featureName += "," + adminboundry3;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adminboundry2)) //Not checking for duplicate here just for this question
                featureName += "," + adminboundry2;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adminboundry1)) //Not checking for duplicate here just for this question
                featureName += "," + adminboundry1;
```

`featureName` contains `PIZZA HUT, ISLAMABAD, PAKISTAN, PAKISTAN`

Comment: thats what i want to minimize

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `string.Join()` method and get array distinct string elements from your object array.

try this:

```
var Result = string.Join(",", values.Cast<string>()
                                 .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c))
                                 .Distinct());
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for, let me try

Comment: +1 The only answer (so far) that included the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` check.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use LINQ:

```
var featureName = String.Join(
  ",",
  values
    .Cast<String>()
    .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    .Distinct()
);
```

Comment: I also need to check for white space or null string

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Join(",",values.ToList().Distinct(str=>str))
```

Comment: I also need to check for white space or null string

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Join(",", values.Distinct().Where(s=>!s.ISNullOrWhiteSpace()))
```